# how to extract id data-value from below div using beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

please help me. I've tried many things but I'm unable to do this.

```
<div class="dfx-singleInstrument__price dfx-rate dfx-font-size-3 font-weight-bold text-right" data-stream-type="price" data-symbol="EURUSD" data-market-id="EURUSD" data-type="bid" data-change-scale="-1" data-unscaling-factor="10000" data-unscaled-decimals="5" data-value="1.18610">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
soup.select_one('.singleInstrument__price')['data-value']
```

Comment: Not working. It gives me type error.                                 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @KashifHussain check the site response code firstly, and make sure it's not a JS site

Comment: Yeah, it's JS site. What should I do now to scrap data? Which library should i use?

Comment: @KashifHussain try `selenium` , or search for an API which feed the JS

Comment: import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.dailyfx.com/forex-rates#currencies'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
inside_div = soup.find_all('span',{'class': 'dfx-singleInstrument__change'})[0]
inside_div                                                                              with this code i'm getting   { <span class="dfx-singleInstrument__change dfx-rate dfx-font-size-2 align-text-top" data-market-id="EURUSD" data-stream-type="price" data-symbol="EURUSD" data-type="change" data-value="---"> }
</span>

Comment: I'm using Selenium now,............ I've xpath of that div ..... low= driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//*[@id="currencies"]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]').text......... but I don't know how to scrap 'data-value' from below script............<span class="dfx-singleInstrument__change dfx-rate dfx-font-size-2 align-text-top" data-market-id="EURUSD" data-stream-type="price" data-symbol="EURUSD" data-type="change" data-value="---">

Comment: please reply sir

Comment: @KashifHussain Comment section is not for expanding your question, Kindly [edit] your question and insert the codes which you've tried out so we can help you.